# SlidingTabLayout error

Tags: java, android

When I try to add *SlidingTabLayout* in xml file it gets me an error

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayoutTop"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar">
    </include>

    <com.android4devs.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Here is the logcat

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android4devs.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myapplication-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

How can I correct it?

Comment: It seems that dex file doesn't include SlidingTabLayout class information. Do you place that class in your project or include library?

Comment: I've put SlidingTabLayout.java & SlidingTabStrip.java from IOsched Google App in my project

Comment: Is `SlidingTabLayout.java` in your package `com.android4devs.slidingtab`?

Comment: @Xcihnegn I should add it in gradle?

Comment: No, just use the real package name + SlidingTabLayout

Comment: @Xcihnegn sorry dor my dumbness, where exactly should I add it?

Comment: Tell me where you put `SlidingTabLayout.java & SlidingTabStrip.java` in your project? and what their package name?

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of

```
 <com.android4devs.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>
```

Please verify the path of SlidingTabLayout. It should be your.package.SlidiingTabLayout